# What wires to use in wiring loom for 1986 CG125

Tags: honda, motorcycle, wiring, wiring-diagram

I have an old 1986 CG125 6V motorcycle that needs patches/extensions to the current wiring loom.
What gauge wires do I need to use (amps and thickness)? I have the Haynes Manual but cannot find the details of this anywhere.
My Wiring is the same on Page 103 for Early Honda CG125 models.

Comment: Same gauge as the wires you are patching.

Comment: Fantastic answer @Moab. Now how do I find out what they are?

Comment: If I was there and could eyeball them and I could tell you. Most automotive wiring is 18,16,14,12 or 10 gauge, larger the number the smaller the wire inside the insulation. By the way it was not an answer, its a comment. Answer would be in the answer box.

Comment: Strip back some insulation on the wire you wish to extend - count the strands and pick up a similar replacement - experience will enable you to get the correct one most times before stripping it...

Answer (score 1):

Get a set of [wire ferrules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_wire_ferrule).
Strip back some insulation and use the ferrules as a gauge to measure the thickness of the conductor.

Buy automotive grade wires. In doubt use some slightly larger diameter.

Comment: Also match the style. Meaning stranded vs solid. (Almost all the wires probably are stranded. )